# Null checking on CASE Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have tried to check value, and if is it null(nothing to show) I deduce empty string. I was trying :

```
SELECT nullif(order_id, ' ') as order_id FROM label_pass_voucher WHERE order_id = 3447;
select CASE WHEN order_id then order_id else ' ' end as order_id FROM label_pass_voucher WHERE order_id = 3447;
```

it doesn't deduce nothing. Where is my fault? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the query you're looking for is:

```
SELECT IFNULL(order_id, '') AS order_id
FROM label_pass_voucher
WHERE order_id = 3447;
```

MySQL official documentation:

> If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns
>   expr2.

`NULLIF()` does a slightly different thing:

> Returns NULL if expr1 = expr2 is true, otherwise returns expr1. This
>   is the same as CASE WHEN expr1 = expr2 THEN NULL ELSE expr1 END.

Answer (score 0):

Use [IFNULL(exp1, exp2)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

```
SELECT IFNULL(order_id, ' ') FROM label_pass_voucher WHERE order_id = 3447;
```

This syntax equivalent to `exp1 == null ? exp2 : exp1`